# Determine whether a categorical grammar is minimal concerning lexical entries

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, minimization

In order to compare the descriptional complexity of context-free and (combinatoric) categorical I need a way to check if a categorical grammar of a formal language is minimal concerning lexical entries.

Any ideas on how to do that? Any work on this, that you might know of?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if you are reading this, Ronny, I really like to get in touch with you! :)

Comment: Could you remind everyone what a CCG is, and explain what "minimal concerning lexical entries" might mean, or point to relevant sources?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide that. For combinatoric categorial grammars please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_categorial_grammar. By "minimal concerning lexical entries" I mean that there is no grammar describing the same language with fewer lexical entries.